# Why is editing upload_max_filesize in php.in not working?

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, apache

I tried to upload file on wordpress but it didn't allow me to do so because the file size was larger than the limit.
After googling the problem, I accessed my website info through ssh and edited the php.ini file to increase the following settings:

```
upload_max_filesize = 512M
post_max_size = 512M
memory_limit = 512M
```

PS: I noticed that this also changed the info in the php-7.2.ini which seems to be an exact copy of php.ini.

After changing those settings I restarted httpd and went to my website. The upload limit was at 1M and I tried uploading the file again and it still didn't work...

I'm running out of possible solutions so if someone could help me out, that'd be awesome!

PS: I don't know if this matters but the wordpress I have is running with the multisite option ON. I only currently have 1 website on it.
Also don't know if this matters, but I also route my www.example.com domain to my example.com domain in Route 53 in AWS and read somewhere that the server might be creating 2 separate instances on the server. Adding the multisite functionality worked fine when I edited the wp-config.php file so I figured the double instance thing was not a problem but I'm still mentioning it here just in case.

Comment: Are you sure you're updating the correct php.ini file? Maybe you should make a phpinfo()  file to check and make sure the location of the file is the correct one, especially if you're running several PHP versions.

Comment: Both php.ini files i found were updated. Idk if there’s more of them...

Comment: Either create a php file with this code inside: `<?php phpinfo();` or run `php --ini` in the terminal to get the correct location. By using the file, all you have to do is search for the path on the tables. Maybe the command is the easiest choice.

Comment: There are also plugins that will tell you which php.ini is being used. One is:  https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-php-settings/

Comment: Installing a plugin only to tell where the php.ini file is located sounds overkill. It's like using a crane to pick apples.

Comment: @Zeke after running the command I got:                                                     
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /etc/php-7.2.conf:/etc
Loaded Configuration File:         /etc/php.ini
Scan for additional .ini files in: /etc/php-7.2.d
Additional .ini files parsed:      /etc/php-7.2.d/20-bz2.ini...                  The ini file in Loaded configuration file is the one I edited. In the list of Additional .ini files parsed I founf a php.ini file inside the php-7.2.d folder and opened it but it said that the main ini file was moved to the one i already edited...

Comment: @Zeke so i opened the folder php-7.2.conf and there was README that I opened and that said to copy the php.ini file and place it here ONLY IN php 7.1... I am assuming I have to change the Configuration File to take the php.ini file instead of '/etc/php-7.2.conf:/etc'? Does that sound right?

Comment: @Zeke I also checked for php-fpm in my service list to restart it but it's not in the service list... And someone said the create a user.ini file in "Additional .ini files parsed" directory, which I did, and it also did not work.....

Comment: My Wordpress knowledge is rusty, but I remember that themes can override some global settings. A quick `grep` in themes dir might be in order.

Comment: Okay, with all that information, I think you are indeed updating the correct file. The one that matters is Loaded Configuration File, so that seems to be the one. There may be an override through php functions (`ini_set()`), so @OleksiiDonoha is actually on the right track. That would sure be very unfortunate though, because why would a theme require such settings, am I right? Take a look at your files to see if there is any override.

Comment: So, quick update. I looked for upload_max_filesize and "ini_set" in all theme files and nothing was found... I honestly don't know where to look anymore... Is there a way to show me what ini files were processed when building the website (On the website itself, maybe it shows more info than php --ini shows)?